# Will an additional SSD Drive fit into Dell Latitude E5420 laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, dell-latitude

I want to make my laptop boot faster and thinking of purchasing an SSD Drive. I have Dell Latitude E5420 model. Will it be able to take an additional SSD Drive into it?

Comment: I highly recommend replacing the HDD with the SSD, and placing the former in the caddy for best results. Don't place the SSD with the OS in the caddy, instead just use it for the secondary data drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to purchase a caddy (such as the one pictured below), you could achieve this.

Keep in mind you will need to reload your OS on the SSD drive in order to get faster boot times.

[image]

Comment: Just like that caddy tray right there.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that model has two seperate hdd bays for a second hdd. but alot of laptops make a custom caddy tray that you can mount a 2.5" hdd into and it replaces the optical drive with a second hdd instead.   I cannot find and exact tray for the e5420 but the e5410 tray should fit fine but with a mismatch case panel on edge. (where the cd drive edge would be)

check out http://www.newmodeus.com/ for parts and answers to this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a hard-drive caddy that replaces the CD drive tray. But my recommendation would be to purchase a hybrid drive that has both a ssd and hdd built into one..
http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/

Comment: +1 for giving me knowledge about this type of drive also exists (Hybrid Drive)

Comment: did not know either. just ordered one